# jqGrid - URL empty on second trigger reload

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

jqGrid - grid populates just fine using external textfield search. If I go to another page then come back and refire the search, the url is not passed in, so no call is made.

In the jqgrid scrfipt at line 2563, the ts.p.url is empty. But my code provides a url in the reloadgrid code. The reload works the first time through, but not the second.

```
            case "script":
                $.ajax($.extend({
                    url:ts.p.url,
                    type:ts.p.mtype,
                    dataType: dt ,
```

Grid code:

```
$("#orchard-grid").jqGrid({
    styleUI: "Bootstrap",
    datatype: 'json',
    colNames: ['Tree Id', "Orchard Name", 'Row', 'Column', 'GID', 'Clone', 'Status'],
    colModel: [
            { name: "TreeId", key: true, hidden: true },
            { name: "OrchardName", search: true },
            { name: "GridRow", search: false },
            { name: "GridColumn", search: false },
            { name: "GID", search: true },
            { name: "Clone", search: true },
            { name: "LocationStatus", search: false}
    ],
    loadonce: false,
    height: 400,
    autowidth: true,
    rowNum: -1,
    ajaxGridOptions: { cache: false},
    onSelectRow: function (id) {
        EditRow(id);
    }
});
```

This is the function that just stops without triggering:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var gid = $("#gidNumber").val();
var orchard = $("#OrchardSelect").val();
var url = $("#GridUrl").val();

if (gid !== "" ) {
    $("#orchard-grid").jqGrid('setGridParam', {
        dataType: "json", 
        url: url,
        postData: {
            gidNumber: gid
        }
    }).trigger('reloadGrid');
}

if (orchard !== "") {
    $("#orchard-grid").jqGrid('setGridParam', {
        dataType: "json", 
        url: url,
        postData: {
            orchardSelect: orchard
        }
    }).trigger('reloadGrid');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the grid was not done loading when I was trying to populate it.  I fixed it by moving the reload function in the loadComplete event of the grid, so the grid would be done rendering before being asked to reload.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#Tab1").click( function(){ 

 var gridArrayData = [];
   var ids =jQuery("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow'); 
   var totalRowsCount = ids.length;
   if(totalRowsCount>0)
  {
   $.ajax({ 
     type: "POST", 
     url: 'Operaciones_Grilla.php?Op=30'+'&Filtro='+ids+'&page=1&rows=10', 
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data) {
  $("#jqGrid2")[0].grid.beginReq();
      var data = data.rows;
  var ii =0;
        for(var i in data)
               {
      
      
      gridArrayData.push({
                                id: data[i].id,
                                sistema: data[i].des_sistema,
                                opcion: data[i].des_opciones_sistema,
        id_sistema:data[i].id_sistema,
        id_opcion:data[i].id
        
                            });                            
                }// cierra el for each
       jQuery('#jqGrid2').jqGrid('clearGridData')
                     .jqGrid('setGridParam', {data: gridArrayData})
                     .trigger('reloadGrid');
     
      $("#jqGrid2")[0].grid.endReq();
      $("#jqGrid2").trigger('reloadGrid');
         }
           }); 
         $('#tabs a[href="#tabs-2"]').trigger('click'); 
         }else{
         alert('debe escoger un registro') ;
     }// cierra el íf que cuenta el numero de registros
 });










//*************** PHP CODE ************************//


Operaciones_Grilla.php?Op=30 call this function :

 public function Sube_Data_Grid_Perfiles22($page,$rows,$filtro)
   {
    
   $respuesta = new stdClass();
      $this->page =$page;
   $this->limit=$rows;
   $sql="";
   $sql='select count(a.*) from opciones_sistema a where a.id_opciones_sistema in  '."(".$filtro.")";
   
         $count = $this->dbh2->query($sql)->fetchColumn();
   if( $count >0 ) {
                 $total_pages = ceil($count/$this->limit);
               } else {
                 $total_pages = 0;
               }
              if ($this->page > $total_pages)$this->page=$total_pages;
       
             $start = $this->limit*$page - $this->limit; 
           $i=0;

           $Sql='select a.id_opciones_sistema, b.des_sistema,a.des_opciones_sistema, b.id_sistema from opciones_sistema a,sistemas b where a.id_sistema = b.id_sistema and a.id_opciones_sistema in '."(".$filtro.") order by b.id_sistema,a.id_opciones_sistema ";
  
  $stmt = $this->dbh2->prepare($Sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  
  
  
  foreach ($stmt as $row) {
  
          $respuesta->rows[$i]['id']=$row["id_opciones_sistema"];
    $respuesta->rows[$i]['des_sistema']=$row["des_sistema"];
    $respuesta->rows[$i]['des_opciones_sistema']=$row["des_opciones_sistema"];
    $respuesta->rows[$i]['id_sistema']=$row["id_sistema"];
                
                $i++;
  
   
   }// cierra sube data grid

     $this->dbh2 = null;
 
  return json_encode($respuesta);
 
 
  
   
}// cierra metodo suba data grid
```

Comment: Did you try to run your code snippet? 'Error: { "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function", ...}' Perhaps you should add an explanation as to how this code is supposed to work and how it answers the question.

Comment: Hello this is a code fragment you have to adapt it to your project.Greetings from Venezuela